# Stream<Stream<dynamic>> instead of Stream<dynamic>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

### Introduction

Hello everyone,

I am building a getter function which should return a **stream with participants of a chat conversation** when a Firestore stream emit a new value.

#### Firestore stream

```dart
Stream<QuerySnapshot> theStream = Firestore.instance.collection("chat").document(uid).collection("participants").snapshots();
```

where the `uid` is the unique id of a conversation.

#### Participants

A participant is defined by a `Profile` object (which contains some usefull fields, like the first name or the last name).

```dart
class Profile {
  String uid;

  ImageProvider profilePicture;

  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  String bio;

  Profile(this.uid);
```

### Expectations

I want to perform some *Futures* actions inside my `theStream.map((snapshot) {...})`, like updating participants `firstName` & `lastName` when a participant `uid` is received. So, to use the `await` keyword, I need to change

```dart
theStream.map((snapshot) {...})
```

to

```dart
theStream.map((snapshot) async* {...})
```

### Issue

In the end of the code, I would have an object with the type

```dart
Stream<List<Profile>>
```

but I have

```dart
Stream<Stream<List<Profile>>>
```

### My code

```dart
Stream<List<Profile>> get updateParticipants() {
    Firestore.instance.collection("chat").document(uid)
        .collection("participants")
        .snapshots()
        .map((participantsSNAP) async* {
      var updates = <Future>[];

      // Pour chaque valeur du serveur
      for (var participantSNAP in participantsSNAP.documentChanges) {
        // Pour chaque valeur du cache
        for (var i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
          // Si serveur = cache
          if (participantSNAP.document.documentID == participants[i].uid) {
            if (participantSNAP.type == DocumentChangeType.removed) {
              participants.removeAt(i);
            } else if (participantSNAP.type == DocumentChangeType.modified) {
              updates.add(participants[i].updateUserProfile());
            }
          } else if (participantSNAP.type == DocumentChangeType.added) {
            participants
                .add(Profile(participantSNAP.document.data["participants"]));
            updates.add(participants[i].updateUserProfile());
          }
        }
      }

      await Future.wait(updates);
      participants.sort((profileA, profileB) =>
          profileA.firstName.compareTo(profileB.firstName));

      return participants
    });
```

**How can I avoid this stream in a stream type?**